# How to have multiple relationships to same table using sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm working on a small movies API using Flask and I have this model.

```
class Episode(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True)

    title = db.Column(db.String(75), nullable=False)

    duration = db.Column(db.String(5), nullable=False)

    # The id of the tv show this episode belongs to
    show_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("tv_show.id"))

    previous = relationship("Episode", back_populates="next")
    next = relationship("Episode", back_populates="previous")
```

The *previous* and *next* columns are supposed to reference the episode that goes before and the one that goes after the current one but whenever I try to do a request to the API I get this error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Episode.previous - there are no foreign keys linking these tables.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.
```

I kind of understand the error but I'm not sure on how to fix it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar where I needed a parents/children structure for records in a table. Since mine was MtM I had to define a table to join ids on, but since yours is one to one you might be able to get away with not doing that. Perhaps something like this:

```
prev_id = db.Column(Integer, db.ForeignKey('episode.id'))
previous = relationship('Episode', uselist=False, # uselist=False makes it 1 to 1
    primary_join = id == Episode.id,
    secondary_join = id == Episode.prev_id, backref=db.backref('next'))
```

Not 100% sure this will work, but it should be heading in the right direction. Here's what I used to get my setup working:

```
node_children = db.Table('node_children',
    db.Column('parent_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('node.id'), primary_key=True),
    db.Column('child_id',  db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('node.id'), primary_key=True)
)

class Node(db.Model):
    children = db.relationship('Node', secondary = node_children, 
        primaryjoin = id == node_children.c.parent_id, 
        secondaryjoin = id == node_children.c.child_id, backref=db.backref('parents'))
```