# Multiple relashionship to the same table - SQLAlachemy (flask)

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I've two tables, being them Users and Documents. Each document must have two users, one is the owner and the other is the signer.

```py
class UserModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = db.Column(db.String(32), primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(256), nullable=False)

    documents_onwer = db.relationship("DocumentModel", primaryjoin = "UserModel.id == DocumentModel.owner_id", lazy="dynamic")
    documents_signer = db.relationship("DocumentModel", primaryjoin = "UserModel.id == DocumentModel.signer_id", lazy="dynamic")
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = uuid.uuid4().hex

class DocumentModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "documents"
    
    id = db.Column(db.String(32), primary_key=True)
    owner_id = db.Column(db.String(32), db.ForeignKey("users.id"), unique=False, nullable=False)
    signer_id = db.Column(db.String(32), db.ForeignKey("users.id"), unique=False, nullable=False)

    user = db.relationship("UserModel", foreign_keys=[owner_id])
    signer = db.relationship("UserModel", foreign_keys=[signer_id])

    def __init__(self):
        self.id = uuid.uuid4().hex
```

When running to get all documents, I'm able to find its owner and signer. However, when getting the users, I'm not able to find the documents which he is the owner and neither the signer.

When trying to print the query from user.documents_user, it returns:

```sql
SELECT documents.owner_id AS owner_id, documents.signer_id AS signer_id, documents.id AS documents_id, 
FROM documents
WHERE ? = documents.owner_id
```

which makes me think that the problem is related to this `WHERE = ?`

To be honest, I'm not sure if this is needed and the usual action would be to just user a join in the query when this information is needed or if it makes sense so actually do this.

---

I've checked two interesting posts here, though I could not make it happen, they are related to the issue and might help.

- [How to have multiple relationships to same table using sqlalchemy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70438317/how-to-have-multiple-relationships-to-same-table-using-sqlalchemy)
- [How to define two relationships to the same table in SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548033/how-to-define-two-relationships-to-the-same-table-in-sqlalchemy)